# WaterFall in CorePlot

Tags: iphone, ipad, charts, core-plot, waterfall

How to plot waterfall chart using coreplot in ipad.I am able to draw pie chart and other chart but not getting way to draw it. please share if any one have working example it will be very helpfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a bar plot. Set `barBasesVary` to `YES` on the plot and return base values from your datasource in addition to the usual location and tip values.